# How can I prevent a method from being wrongly overridden

Tags: objective-c, methods, overriding

How can I prevent a method from getting overridden in a subclass, missing a call to its superclass' implementation within?.
I know calling `[super methodName];` will solve my problem sometimes.
But if somebody else was to use my parent class and overrode my method, accidentally missing to call super, what can I do?

Some more explanations:

I create a viewcontroller VC1 which has a method `-(void)indexDidChange:(int)index { }`. I write some actions there which I need to perform every time. and I subclass this viewcontroller named as SVC1 in it I need `-(void)indexDidChange:(int)index { }` for doing some other actions but at the same time the VC1 `-(void)indexDidChange:(int)index { }` action also need to perform. So I need to call like,

```
 -(void)indexDidChange:(int)index { 
[super indexDidChange:index];
}
```

So I decide to change VC1 function like,

```
  -(void)indexDidChange:(int)index {
     [self currentIndexDidChange:(int)index];
 }

-(void)currentIndexDidChange:(int)index { }
```

And I need -(void)currentIndexDidChange:(int)index { } to override and prevent -(void)indexDidChange:(int)index { } from overriding.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You seem to be mixing up the concepts of **private methods** with *final methods*. Do you want to **prevent calling** of a method from a class' subclasses or do you want to **prevent overriding** of a method from a class' subclasses? These are two entirely different things.

Comment: @Regexident, Is it clear now? Any Hope?. thanks for replies....

Comment: Yes, thanks. So apparently contrary to your original phrasing you aren't looking for final methods at all. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: After OP rephrased the question it is clear that OP is actually NOT looking for **final methods**, despite the questions initial phrasing, which implied just this.

### New (updated) answer to OP's question on method overriding safety:

According to your rephrased question you are not looking for protecting a method from being overridden at all, but rather worried about one of your subclasses overriding a method and accidently missing to include a call to super in its new implementation.

This however is a **fairly common and widespread issue** and something you're dealing with on a daily basis, without paying much attention to it.

Every Objective-C programmer is familiar with the following method, right?

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [iVar release], iVar = nil;
    [super dealloc]; //skipping this call to super is fatal!
}
```

And we al know that skipping the `[super dealloc];` makes things get uncomfortable. (afaik the clang compiler issues a warning if dealloc lacks the call to super, …pretty handy.)

Despite the fact that a bad overriding of this method can have fatal consequences Apple did not choose to put any kind of security system in place here.

**Instead Apple did this** (as done with any other method requiring calls to super):

- **Add a note to the method's documentation:**

> [After performing the class-specific
>   deallocation, the subclass method
>   should incorporate superclass versions
>   of dealloc through a message to
>   super](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc)

- **Expect you**, the programmer, **to be a grown-up and responsible for what you do**. And for playing by the rules (as defined by the documentation).

Keep in mind that `- (void)dealloc` is by no means an exception. There are dozens and dozens of methods of this type in Cocoa. (Take just about any derivative of `- (id)init`, most of the KVO observing methods, etc. just to name a few.)

So what you should do is:

1. **Write a good documentation for your
   method**. (better **for your entire project**, actually)
2. **Add a big *loud* note to your method's documentation, explaining its rules.**
3. **Add a note to each of your subclasses' overridden method implementations**, right above the line that's calling `super`, telling the reader/dev to look up documentation, when in doubt of the rules. (optional)
4. **Code responsibly. Otherwise, you shouldn't be coding in first place.** It's your customers who will suffer from it, eventually.

---

### Old (pre-rephrasing) answer on archieving pseudo-final methods:

What you are asking for is the equivalent of a **final function**, as known from Java or C++.
Unlike Java or C++, however there are no **final methods** in Objective-C.

Depending on your situation there are solutions that might **bring your at least near to what you're aiming for**. **All you'll get though is slightly better separation**. You **won't get any significant security** from them. In Objective-C you cannot even be sure about the origin of your methods. **Method swizzling** allows you to **exchange methods at will**. With **code injection** you an even **inject code into processes at runtime**. All this is by design of Objective-C. Objective-C allows you to saw off the branch you're sitting on. Thus it demands you to act like a grown-up. As such there are no private methods either. If a method is proclaim private you as a dev are expected to behave accordingly.

Now to possible "*solutions*":

If only your super class if supposed to call the given (final) method anyway:

1. Then **Macmade**'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648589/how-can-i-prevent-a-method-from-overriding-iphone-objc/5648676#5648676) of **making your method a pseudo-private method** would work quite well. The downside of hiding method declarations though is, that calling your hidden method from subclasses will give you a compiler warning, basically preventing*(sic!)* you from calling it. (It **will not prevent** you from calling the method though. It **will only avoid** you from doing so, by throwing compiler warnings.)

If subclasses however are expected to call the given (final) method:

1. Use a [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) and by this only make those methods public that are allowed to be overridden.
2. To prevent overriding at all you could use the [class cluster](http://seanmurph.com/weblog/make-your-own-abstract-factory-class-cluster-in-objective-c/) & [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory) patterns, which hides your implementation classes and thus preventing overriding entirely. (Apple's `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet` classes do this)

However you might notice that with Objective-C lack of protection one usually can only **choose between the two**: openness, protectedness, **not intermix them**.

Comment: Also on a side note When using ARC you do not need to call [super dealloc] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292119/custom-dealloc-and-arc-objective-c

Answer (score 4):

You can use categories in the implementation, so your methods aren't exposed in your header file.

`MyClass.m`

```
@interface MyClass( Private )

- ( void )myMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass( Private )

- ( void )myMethod
{}

@end

@implementation MyClass

/* ... */

@end
```

Comment: @Naveen  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare your function in the ".h file" then its not listed, I think.

Comment: @NaveenShan what does it say and where?